# fT and fmax of a bipolar transistor

Tags: bjt, frequency

I want to find the maximum frequency of the input voltage in a Bipolar inverter. However, I cannot seem to find any formulas or equations for it. Should calculate fT, and if so, how?

[image]

Comment: fT is a property of the transistor, not the circuit. You can estimate it from some other parameter like the effective input capacitance or the transit time, but usually you can't obtain those from the data sheet. Transistor data sheets commonly give values for fT.

Answer (score 3):

You have to calculate the BIAS point of that circuit:

1. Calculate Ib, Ic where Ib = (Vi - 0.7)/Rb
2. Calculate gm = Ic/Vt where Vt ≈ kT/q = 25 mV
3. Evaluate Cπ from the datasheet
4. Calculate ft from the following formula:

[image: ft in BJT's]

Cπ is the diffusion capacitance between the Base and the Emitter.

Cπ is given or it has to be read out from the datasheet.

Cπ usually is in the range 1 pF to 10 pF.

You may neglect Cµ since Cπ is always much higher than Cµ.

Reference:

[https://www.ee.columbia.edu/~bbathula/courses/SSDT/lect10.pdf](https://www.ee.columbia.edu/%7Ebbathula/courses/SSDT/lect10.pdf)

---

These instead are more general formulas for ft and fmax:

[image: ft and fmax in BJT's]

Reference:

https://www.chu.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Chenming-Hu_ch8-2.pdf